# How do I correctly format the DatePicker StyleTemplate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, datepicker, uwp

I need to format an UWP-DatePicker. What I'd like to get would be a common DatePicker which fits inside a grid propperly.

Here is how I embedded the DatePicker inside my GridColumn:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DatePicker Grid.Column="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                MonthFormat="{}{month.abbreviated(3)}" 
                Date="{Binding AppointmentStartDateProxy, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                DateChanged="DatePicker_DateChanged" 
                Style="{StaticResource DatePickerStyle1}"> 
        <DatePicker.IsEnabled>
            <Binding Path="Closed" Converter="{StaticResource negationConverter}"/>
        </DatePicker.IsEnabled>
    </DatePicker>
</Grid>
```

Here are the "crucial" changes to the StyleTemplate:

```
<Style x:Key="DatePickerStyle1" TargetType="DatePicker">
    <.../>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePicker">
                <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                      x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                                      Visibility="Collapsed"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                      Margin="0,0,0,8"
                                      Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                    <Button x:Name="FlyoutButton"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Style="{StaticResource DatePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
```

When setting Style.Setter.Value.ControlTemplate.StackPanel.Button.HorizontalAlignment="Left"
my DatePicker does not fill its parent control:
[image: Button to Small]

When setting Style.Setter.Value.ControlTemplate.StackPanel.Button.HorizontalAlignment="Strech" my DatePicker is overlapping its parent control:
[image: Button overlapping]

This behavior also stays the same when I'm changing the StyleTemplates LayoutRoot from StackPanel to Grid.

In my understanding, the RootLayout-Control should inherit its size from the Grid containing the DatePicker, and the Button should get its size from RootLayout with an result in fitting inside my GridColumn.

EDIT:

When changing only the DatePickers HorizontalAlignment to Strech (and in abscense of a style) it's overlapping the parent grid way to far:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you don't need to change the style or the `Button` alignments. All you need is to set the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch` in both controls. Note that the default value of it is `Left`.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid Width="800">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DatePicker Grid.Column="0" MonthFormat="{}{month.abbreviated(3)}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <TimePicker Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

### Update

One more thing. `DatePicker` has a default `MinWidth` of `296` and `TimePicker` of `242`. So if you could set them to a smaller value, like this -

```
<DatePicker Grid.Column="0" MonthFormat="{}{month.abbreviated(3)}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="80" />
<TimePicker Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="80" />
```

Comment: Hi Justin, see my edit above, it did not work as expected.